# Pandas: select the first value which is not negative anymore, return the row

Tags: python, pandas

For now my code looks like this:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    max_exp = []
    gammastar = []
    for idx,rw in df_gamma_count.iterrows():
        exp = rw['Pr_B']*(rw['gamma_index']*float(test_spread)*(1+f)-(f+f))
        df = df.append({'exp': exp, 'gamma_perc': rw['gamma_index'], 'Pr_B':rw['Pr_B'], 'spread-test in %': test_spread }, ignore_index=True)
        df = df.sort_values(by= ['exp'], ascending=True)
df
```

which gives me the following dataframe:

```
          Pr_B          exp         gamma_perc  spread-test in %
10077   0.000066    -2.078477e-08   1.544700    0.001090292473058004120128368625
10078   0.000066    -2.073422e-08   1.545400    0.001090292473058004120128368625
10079   0.000066    -2.071978e-08   1.545600    0.001090292473058004120128368625
10080   0.000066    -2.071256e-08   1.545700    0.001090292473058004120128368625
10081   0.000000    -0.000000e+00   1.545900    0.001090292473058004120128368625
10082   0.000000    -0.000000e+00   1.546200    0.001090292473058004120128368625
10083   0.000000    0.000000e+00    1.546300    0.001090292473058004120128368625
10084   0.000000    1               1.546600    0.001090292473058004120128368625
```

What I need now is to select the first value from the column `exp` which is not negative anymore. What I did for now is to sort the dataframe based on the column `exp` but after that I am a bit stuck and do not know where to go... any idea?

Comment: If you can `sort` the `DataFrame` by `exp` then what is the definition of "first value"? Do you mean the smallest positive number? or do you mean the first occurrence of a positive value in the original sort order?

Comment: `df.exp.gt(0).idxmax()`?

Comment: @Idlehands, the smallest positive number or the biggest negative number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would screen for number larger than 0 and get the first index

```
data = [-1,-2,-3, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['exp'])
value = df.exp[df.exp >= 0].iloc[0] if df.exp[df.exp >= 0].any() else df.exp.max()
```

Comment: I was not clear enough. In some cases I have data which might be [-3,-2,-1]  and I need to select -1, and in some cases I have [-2,-1,0] then I need to take zero and in the the third sample if I have [-1,0,1] I need to take 0. Do you have line of code which can be applied to all the 3 cases?

Comment: Yes but when I change the data to data = [-1,-2,-3, 0,1] it should give me zero. That is what I explained below, it should give me the smallest positive number and the biggest negative number :)

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: the reason why you are not getting 0 instead of 1 it because the screen is `df.exp > 0` not `df.exp >= 0` I adjusted the answer

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df.loc[df.exp.gt(0).idxmax()]
```

this will - *select the first value from the column exp which is not negative anymore*

if you are tying to get the largest value in a series

```
df.exp.nlargest(1)
```

**EDIT**:

Use this to get your desired output:

```
df.loc[df.exp==np.where(all(i > 0 for i in df.exp.tolist()),min([n for n in df.exp.tolist() if n<=0]),max([n for n in df.exp.tolist() if n<=0]))]


print(df.loc[df.exp==np.where(all(i > 0 for i in df.exp.tolist()),min([n for n in df.exp.tolist() if n<=0]),max([n for n in df.exp.tolist() if n<=0]))].head(1))

   Pr_B  exp  gamma_perc  spread-test in %
4   0.0  0.0      1.5459           0.00109
```

Comment: I was not clear enough. In some cases I have data which might be [-3,-2,-1] and I need to select -1, and in some cases I have [-2,-1,0] then I need to take zero and in the the third sample if I have [-1,0,1] I need to take 0. Do you have line of code which can be applied to all the 3 cases?