# Find where values becomes negative in dataframe row and return corresponding column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      1     2     3     4     5     6     7      8     9
0     2     1     -1    -2    -3    -2    -1     0     1
```

I need to return the column where the value becomes negative and where it becomes positive again.

It is similar to this question but inverted columns and rows:
[Pandas: select the first value which is not negative anymore, return the row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466763/pandas-select-the-first-value-which-is-not-negative-anymore-return-the-row)

Any ideas on simple way to do this?

Expected output would return the column numbers where it changed like so:

```
neg = 3
pos = 8
```

Comment: can you show the expected output as well?

Comment: post updated to show outputs

Comment: what if the df has multiple rows? what do you want to return?

Comment: Yes I was trying to keep it simple but yes it will need to be iterated over a df with many rows

Comment: what if you have multiple cols satisfying this condition? the question is a little vague to me unless you post an example covering all scenarios and an expected output wrt the input

Comment: if the cycle repeat you stil want first indices or what?

Comment: you can modify the code and apply for each row.

Comment: @anky there will only be one column going negative and one column going positive. I am checking PyGirl's solution... will update asap

Comment: its a good question, but agree with @anky you need to provide all scenario's voting to close - happy to remove if you edit your question.

Comment: @Manakin I have answered his question. It will only become negative and postive once for each row.  I think PyGirl's solution will work, just debugging some issues with my code. will edit comments as I make progress

Comment: @Pygirl solution worked perfectly for my scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pandas` + `numpy` solution.
Find the sign changes `np.sign(df1).diff().ne(0)`

```
df = df.replace(0,np.inf)
df1 = df.T
t = df1[np.sign(df1).diff().ne(0)[1:]]
s = (t>0)
pos = [*filter(s[0].get, s.index)]
s = (t<0)
neg = [*filter(s[0].get, s.index)]
```

---

**pos:**

```
['8']
```

**neg:**

```
['3']
```

---

For each row:

```
def get_pos_neg(row):
    t = row[np.sign(row).diff().ne(0)]#[1:]
    print(t)
    s = (t>0)
    pos = [*filter(s.get, s.index)]
    s = (t<0)
    neg = [*filter(s.get, s.index)]
    return pos,neg
  
df = df.replace(0,np.inf)
df1 = df.T
df1.apply(get_pos_neg,0)
```

Comment: Tested on multiple negative sign cases also. It works

Comment: thank you so much.@Pygirl I have a couple columns with text in the beginning. Is there a way to skip columns?

Comment: @andrew852: select column by dtype. Gn will see in the morning if you have issues.

Comment: works perfectly.  used same code in while loop for each row and it works. thanks again all!